# How to make custom Pipes in Angular 2/4 with Javascript (no typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-pipe

I want to make a custom pipe for my angular 4 application, but all of the resources I've found only show how to make pipes in TypeScript. I have to use JavaScript. Can anyone explain how to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: technically typescript transcompiles to javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it. From https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html

```
app.MyPipe = ng.core.Pipe({
  name: 'myPipe'
}).Class({
    constructor: function () {
    }, transform: function (input) {
        return input ? 'Yep' : 'Oh, I don't think so';

    }
});
```